# jdbi version 3, stringtemplate when to escape <, > characters?

Tags: java, jdbi, stringtemplate-4

I am using jdbi3 with StringTemplate 4 templating engine, I have this test query:

```
    @SqlQuery("select * from test "
        + "where field1 = 5"
        + "<if(cond1)> or field2 \\<= :value1<endif>"
        + "<if(cond2)> or field2 >= :value2<endif>"
        + "<if(cond3)> or field2 in (<values>)<endif>")
@RegisterBeanMapper(Test.class)
@UseStringTemplateEngine
public List<Test> selectTest(
        @Define("cond1") boolean cond1, @Bind("value1") int value2,
        @Define("cond2") boolean cond2, @Bind("value2") int value3,
        @Define("cond3") boolean cond3,
        @BindList(value="values", onEmpty=BindList.EmptyHandling.NULL_STRING ) List<Integer> values);
```

Using StringTemplate engine when I have to escape with `\` the characters `<` or `>`  in the query?
Testing I found that I have to escape `<=` in the query like I did.

In the IN clause using `@BindList` I have to use the `<values>` but in this case I was expecting to escape it like `\\<values>` otherwise it will be used as attribute by StringTemplate but if I do this the query doesn't work.

About `>=` escaping it or not seems the same in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Let's consider:

- The `3.27.1` Jdbi version as the current Jdbi version.
- The `4.3.1` StringTemplate version as the current StringTemplate version, since the current Jdbi version uses it. Please, see: [jdbi/pom.xml at v3.27.1 · jdbi/jdbi](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/v3.27.1/pom.xml#L524-L528).

## Answer

### Jdbi

#### Documentation: Which characters to escape

Please, note the warning on which characters to escape:

> Since StringTemplate by default uses the `<` character to mark ST expressions, you might need to escape some SQL: `String datePredSql = "<if(datePredicate)> <dateColumn> \\< :dateFilter <endif>"`
>
> — [jdbi/index.adoc at v3.27.1 · jdbi/jdbi](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/v3.27.1/docs/src/adoc/index.adoc).

#### Unit-test: Do not escape `@BindList` variable name

Please, see the `BindListTest.ifValueGivenWithNullValueOptionThenResultIsTruthy()` test method: [jdbi/BindListTest.java at v3.27.1 · jdbi/jdbi](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/v3.27.1/stringtemplate4/src/test/java/org/jdbi/v3/sqlobject/BindListTest.java#L252).

Please, note that the test covers a very similar annotated method:

```
@SqlQuery("select name from something <if(name)> where name in (<name>) <endif>")
@UseStringTemplateEngine
List<String> getForValue(@Nonnull @BindList(value = "name", onEmpty = NULL_VALUE) List<String> name);
```

Please, note that the `@BindList` variable name is not escaped:

```
in (<name>)
```

### StringTemplate

#### Documentation: Which characters to escape

Please, note which characters to escape:

> A template is a sequence of text and expression elements, optionally interspersed with comments. At the coarsest level, the basic elements are:
>
> ```
> text
> <expr>
> <! comment !>
> ```
>
> Escape delimiters with a backslash character: `\<` or `\>`.
>
> — [stringtemplate4/templates.md at 4.3.1 · antlr/stringtemplate4](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/4.3.1/doc/templates.md).

Comment: How to manage the sql if there are multiple where clause?